# Improve computational speed for chunk-wise distance calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, distance

I have an issue with the performance of a code I have to calculate the distance between vectors, but I think a little context is in order before exposing the problem.

I have two sets of vectors stored in two dataframes. What I want to do is to compute the distance between the every vector in set of vectors in one dataframe to every vector in the other dataframe. Here are examples of how these dataframes looks like (I post these at the end of the question in the form of dictionaries) here only the first 5 lines:

```
df_sample = 

                                                                                                                                        CalVec
1272    [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]
657    [1.44, 12.0, 10.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.23, 4.36, 15.0]
806   [4.58, 13.09, 15.46, 3.59, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 6.31]
771      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 5.59, 11.67, 3.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1370       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 2.89, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
df_sample.to_dict()
```

and

```
DF = 
          id  \
4538   A4060462000516278   
5043   A4050494272716275   
11663  A4070271111316245   
2701   A4060462848716270   
825    A4060454573516274   

                                                                                                                                       MeasVec  
4538     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 15.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 3.0]  
5043   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 12.0, 0.0, 13.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0]  
11663      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
2701      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 16.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0]  
825     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 15.0, 0.0, 13.0, 16.0, 0.0, 9.0, 3.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
df_sample
M = len(DF)
```

In reality `df_sample` has 1700 rows while `DF` has 12000 rows. I provide a sample of 10 and 50 respectively.

Now, to compute the distances (in my full size data) I am forced to chunk the larger dataframe into smaller pieces and in my actual distance computation I need to make sure that the chunks have the same amount of rows as `df_sample`, hence I create empty vectors for every chunk until it matches the length of `df_sample`.

```
M = len(DF)
N = len(df_sample)
P = int(round(M/N,0))-1

Number_of_id = int(round(M/P,0))   #There are only unique id:s in DF
Number_AP = 26

def zerolistmaker(n):
    listofzeros = [0.0] * n
    return listofzeros

def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size): 
    chunks = list()
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        chunks.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
    return chunks

DF_chunked = split_dataframe(DF,Number_of_id)
```

and here I compute the distances (actually, weighted distances, so there is no commutativity, i.e. `d(v1,v2) != d(v2,v1)`).

```
import time
t = time.process_time()
DIST = []
for i in range(P):
    vec = DF_chunked[i]   
    number_zero_vectors = len(vec)-len(df_sample)
    df =pd.DataFrame(columns = ['CalVec'])
    for k in range(number_zero_vectors):
        a = zerolistmaker(Number_AP)
        df = df.append({'CalVec':a},ignore_index=True)

    df_sample_ = pd.concat([df_sample, df])
    
    m = np.repeat(np.vstack(df_sample_['CalVec']), df_sample_.shape[0], axis=0)
    n = np.tile(np.vstack(vec['MeasVec']), (vec.shape[0], 1))

    d = np.count_nonzero(m, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((m - n)**2/d, axis=-1))
    
    mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([vec['id']] * 2, names=['id2','id'])
    out = pd.DataFrame({'CalVec': m.tolist(),
                'MeasVec': n.tolist(),
                'distance': dist}, index=mi).reset_index()
    DIST.append(out)

elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t

distances = pd.concat(DIST)
distances = distances.drop(['id2'], axis = 1)
distances = distances.dropna()
print(elapsed_time)
```

which gives the time `0.0625` and the `distance` df:

```
id  \
0  A4060462000516278   
1  A4050494272716275   
2  A4070271111316245   
3  A4060462848716270   

                                                                                                                                    CalVec  \
0  [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]   
1  [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]   
2  [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]   
3  [0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 2.54, 2.0, 4.91, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.59, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0]   

                                                                                                                                   MeasVec  \
0    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 15.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 3.0]   
1  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 12.0, 0.0, 13.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0]   
2      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
3     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 16.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0]   

   distance  
0      8.98  
1     10.45  
2      8.92  
3      5.19
```

Now, this seems to be fast but it isn't. In fact the time grows exponentially and when considering the entire sets, it takes almost 20 minutes, if the kernel doesn't crash. It is so memory consuming that I cannot do anything else on my computer.

I would appreciate any insight.

**DATA**

```
df_sample = {'CalVec': {1272: [0.0,
   4.0,
   8.0,
   15.0,
   10.0,
   8.0,
   2.54,
   2.0,
   4.91,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.59,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.0],
  657: [1.44,
   12.0,
   10.0,
   5.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.23,
   4.36,
   15.0],
  806: [4.58,
   13.09,
   15.46,
   3.59,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   6.31],
  771: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   5.59,
   11.67,
   3.91,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  1370: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   2.89,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  991: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   9.0,
   1.75,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.5,
   14.71,
   13.0,
   9.0],
  194: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   15.54,
   13.0,
   2.12,
   0.0],
  1128: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.77,
   1.8,
   7.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   1.8,
   0.0,
   9.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   2.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  158: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   15.44,
   13.0,
   2.0],
  580: [0.0,
   2.0,
   6.0,
   15.64,
   2.0,
   2.0,
   9.23,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.23]}}
```

and

```
DF = {'id': {4538: 'A4060462000516278',
  5043: 'A4050494272716275',
  11663: 'A4070271111316245',
  2701: 'A4060462848716270',
  825: 'A4060454573516274',
  8679: 'A4060462010016274',
  11700: 'A4060462080916270',
  8594: 'A4060461067716272',
  8707: 'A4060454363916275',
  1071: 'A4060463723916275',
  7128: 'A4050494407616274',
  8828: 'A4060464006116272',
  8505: 'A4050500855716270',
  9958: 'A4060462054116273',
  2048: 'A4060461032216279',
  8522: 'A4050494268116274',
  10934: 'A4070270449716242',
  10128: 'A4050500604416279',
  9453: 'A4050500735216272',
  11820: 'A4060462873316274',
  7617: 'A4060461991516276',
  6930: 'A4050500905516274',
  11376: 'A4060454760216279',
  5619: 'A4139300114013544',
  35: 'A4050470904716271',
  7957: 'A4090281675416244',
  4216: 'A4050494309816277',
  6244: 'A4050494283216272',
  11922: 'A4070271196316248',
  8914: 'A4060461041916276',
  6054: 'A4060462056416278',
  12014: 'A4060464023316273',
  1362: 'A4050494275316274',
  749: 'A4620451876116275',
  4405: 'A4620451903216277',
  2021: 'A4060454386016271',
  7175: 'A4060462829816270',
  351: 'A4060454654316272',
  5853: 'A4050494877016279',
  7980: 'A4050500932116270',
  17: 'A4620451899116270',
  8234: 'A4050494361416271',
  10271: 'A4050500470516271',
  1325: 'A4050500771516275',
  2391: 'A4050500683216274',
  372: 'A4050494830916277',
  5527: 'A4050490253316276',
  5431: 'A4050500884316278',
  717: 'A4060461998716275',
  10015: 'A4050500032916279'},
 'MeasVec': {4538: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   15.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.5,
   0.0,
   3.0],
  5043: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   12.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   3.0,
   0.0],
  11663: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  2701: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   13.0,
   16.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   7.0],
  825: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   9.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  8679: [0.0,
   4.0,
   9.0,
   15.0,
   10.0,
   3.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   9.0],
  11700: [0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   8.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   6.0],
  8594: [12.0,
   16.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   0.0,
   5.0],
  8707: [7.0,
   5.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.0,
   15.0],
  1071: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   15.5,
   6.0,
   3.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  7128: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   10.0,
   15.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   12.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   11.0],
  8828: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   15.0,
   15.0,
   7.0],
  8505: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   16.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  9958: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   14.0,
   9.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   6.0],
  2048: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   14.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  8522: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   4.0,
   16.0,
   9.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   14.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.5,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  10934: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   8.0,
   4.5,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  10128: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   12.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   5.0,
   3.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  9453: [0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  11820: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   10.0,
   9.0,
   15.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  7617: [0.0,
   3.0,
   10.0,
   9.0,
   15.0,
   11.0,
   8.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   2.0,
   15.0],
  6930: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   10.0,
   15.5,
   14.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  11376: [0.0,
   0.0,
   10.0,
   7.0,
   7.0,
   11.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   16.0],
  5619: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   12.0,
   14.0,
   2.5,
   2.0,
   8.0],
  35: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  7957: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.5,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   8.0,
   4.5,
   4.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  4216: [16.0,
   6.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   5.0],
  6244: [11.0,
   7.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   10.0],
  11922: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  8914: [2.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   15.0],
  6054: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   9.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   0.0,
   6.0],
  12014: [3.0,
   7.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   14.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   16.0],
  1362: [15.0,
   16.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0],
  749: [14.0,
   15.0,
   16.0,
   3.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   2.0,
   12.0],
  4405: [11.0,
   16.0,
   16.0,
   3.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0],
  2021: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   6.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  7175: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   9.0,
   16.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   5.0],
  351: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   16.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   5.0],
  5853: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   8.0,
   1.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  7980: [0.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   8.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0],
  17: [11.0,
   16.0,
   16.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   11.0],
  8234: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   7.0,
   5.0,
   11.0,
   13.0,
   0.0,
   13.0,
   3.0,
   11.0,
   15.0,
   12.0,
   12.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  10271: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   9.0,
   0.0,
   15.0,
   9.0,
   5.0,
   5.0],
  1325: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   9.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  2391: [0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0],
  372: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   16.0,
   10.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   6.0,
   0.0],
  5527: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   14.0,
   16.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  5431: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   3.0,
   8.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   16.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  717: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   2.0,
   14.0,
   9.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  10015: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   14.0,
   16.0,
   15.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   9.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   3.0,
   12.0]}}
```

Comment: One insight is that you are calling the zerolistmaker function many times in your second for-loop. This would lead to creating a list of 26 zeros many times, thus increasing your memory every time this function is called. I would suggest calling the function once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance calculation is a common problem, so it can be a good idea to use the available functions for that, specifically `sklearn`. The data you provided is not convenient to manage, but the example below might give ideas on how to adapt this workflow to the specifics of your data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 30))
Y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 30))


def custom_distance(x, y):
    """Sample asymmetric function."""
    return max(x) + min(y)

# use n_jobs=-1 to run calculations with all cores
result = pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric=custom_distance, n_jobs=-1)
```

To complete @SultanOrazbayev:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances


Ax = df_sample['CalVec'] = df_sample['CalVec'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
Bx = DF['MeasVec'] = DF['MeasVec'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

A = Ax.to_numpy()
B = Bx.to_numpy()
AA = np.stack(A)
BB = np.stack(B)

result = pairwise_distances(AA, BB, metric=custom_distance, n_jobs=-1)
```

which is performed in under 3 minutes.

Comment: I really like the idea, it would most definitely save me quite a lot of work. However, it does seem as straightforward as you say it is because I need to pass vectors to ```pairwise_distances```. But, thank you!

Comment: Converting the data to numpy arrays might help, but yes I might be optimistic with 'straightforward' part... it rarely is.